# Capybara, Rspec how to click span element

Tags: rspec, capybara

Issues

```
<span _sort="view.sub_domain" class="sort_both">Host</span>
```

How to click this span
tried

```
page.find('.sort_both', text: 'Host').click
```

Failure
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:

Comment: This looks like it should work, so it's possible that the element is not showing up on the page quickly enough. Can you try setting `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to something like `30` and trying again?

Comment: Can you please write an example for it

Comment: In your `spec_helper.rb`, you can set the default wait time by adding `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 30`.  Then re-run your test and see if it passes.